# How can I update the content of certain column without any page loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

`User` has_one `UserProfile`.
Then `UserProfile` has `wanted_message` column as string.

Here, I'm showing input box to update `wanted_message`
I want it to be updated if certain user inputs any message then press "Update" button.

How can I? now, It's taking me to the url "/users/12" if I press "Update"

I don't want that:( I want it to be updated without any page loading(Ajax Request).
Then I want to have Action called `update_message` in **User contoroller**

How can I?

```
    <%= form_for(current_user, :url => {:controller => "user", :action => "update_message" }, :remote => true, :class => 'form-search') do |f| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |profile_form| %>
            <div class="input-append">
                <%= profile_form.text_field :wanted_message, :class => 'span6' %>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Update</button>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `remote => true` in your form and also set `:method => put` Put lets you update columns in your database and `remote true` will configure the form to send an ajax request.  You'll also have to configure the `update_message` action in your controller to handle ajax requests.  Finally, make sure your routes are configured correctly.  You'll have to define that route in routes.rb and probably do an `:as => 'update_message'` to have access to that route helper method

This may help you with ajax in rails forms http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Here's a sample form, it's in haml though:

```
  = link_to "Start", polls_toggle_live_path(poll.id), :method => :put, :remote => true, :class=> 'btn btn-success btn-small start-poll', :id => poll.id
```

**Which links to this controller action**

```
  def toggle_live
    @poll = Poll.find(params[:poll_id])
    @poll.toggle_live
    @poll.save!
  end
```

**Calls this method in the associated polls model to switch the db column value**

```
  def toggle_live
    self.is_live = !self.is_live
  end
```

**Finally its configured in routes.rb this way to pass along the correct updates**

```
match '/polls/toggle_live/:poll_id' => 'polls#toggle_live', :via => :put, :as => 'polls_toggle_live'
```

Comment: `<%= form_for current_user, :remote => true, :method => put, :class => 'form-search' do |f| %>`???